# How to make sql (postgresql) query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
/* Create a table called tbl1 */
CREATE TABLE tbl1(id integer PRIMARY KEY, name text, lang text);

/* Create few records in this table */
INSERT INTO tbl1 VALUES(1,'John', 'Perl');
INSERT INTO tbl1 VALUES(2,'Pete', 'Perl');
INSERT INTO tbl1 VALUES(3,'Sam', 'Java');
INSERT INTO tbl1 VALUES(4,'John', 'Php');
INSERT INTO tbl1 VALUES(5,'Sam', 'Perl');
INSERT INTO tbl1 VALUES(6,'Sam', 'Php');
INSERT INTO tbl1 VALUES(7,'Pete', 'C');
INSERT INTO tbl1 VALUES(8,'Bob', 'Java');
```

Derive the names of those who know Perl and Php.

Comment: have you tried anything at all?

Comment: First, normalise your data...

Comment: there will be about 20-30 viable answers to this from pivot to semi hacky.  this seems like homework though, you should probably attempt learning an answer to this.

Comment: normalise my data?) the task is correct, Matt

Comment: Twelfth, show me one your answer please. I found 1 solution, but I want to see another.

Answer (score 0):

The OP contained very Little information. Is this what you need?

```
SELECT Name
FROM tbl1
WHERE lang = 'Perl' AND lang = 'Php'
```

For future reference; you really should provide a minimal working example, as you have done here, but also what you have actually tried, which you lacked.

If this query is what you need, then it is very straight-forward and your problem should have been managable with just googling some minutes.

Comment: No, this query return 0 rows

Comment: Must return names 'Sam' and 'John'.

Comment: `lang = 'Perl' AND lang = 'Php'` can never be true

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT distinct(name)
FROM tbl1
WHERE name IN (SELECT name FROM tbl1 WHERE lang = 'Perl')
  AND name IN (SELECT name FROM tbl1 WHERE lang = 'Php');
```

**Is it good answer? I don't think so.**
I want to find better way.

2 additional answers

```
SELECT n FROM (
  SELECT tbl1.name, string_agg(tbl1.lang, '-')
  FROM tbl1
  GROUP BY name) AS t (n, l)
WHERE
  position('Perl' in l) <> 0
AND
  position('Php' in l) <> 0;
```

===================================

```
SELECT t1.name FROM (
  SELECT name FROM tbl1 WHERE lang = 'Perl'
) AS t1, (
  SELECT name FROM tbl1 WHERE lang = 'Php'
) AS t2
WHERE t1.name = t2.name;
```